# an algorithm to compute variance is not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a function that is supposed to return variances of the R,G,B components of a set of pixels in a given cluster.

```py
def RGB_variance(img, density):
    R_total = 0
    G_total = 0
    B_total = 0
    N = len(density)

    for pixel in density:
        x = pixel[0]
        y = pixel[1]
        R_total += img[x][y][0]
        G_total += img[x][y][1]
        B_total += img[x][y][2]

    R_mean, G_mean, B_mean = R_total/N, G_total/N, B_total/N

    R_sum = 0
    G_sum = 0
    B_sum = 0

    means = [R_mean, G_mean, B_mean]

    sums = [R_sum, G_sum, B_sum]

    for pixel in density:
        x = pixel[0]
        y = pixel[1]
        for i in range(0,3):
            sums[i] += (img[x][y][i] - means[i])**2

    variances = {
    "R_variance":sums[0]/N, 
    "G_variance":sums[1]/N, 
    "B_variance":sums[2]/N,
    }

    return variances
```

these photos show the region I'm working on and the corresponding pixels:

https://i.ibb.co/djd1b97/1.png

https://i.ibb.co/NxkX703/1.png

the result I'm given is and Its not quite right:

```py
{'R_variance': 71.56184661531957, 'G_variance': 91.47570122951443, 'B_variance': 521.035179427894}
```

how could the B component variance is 521 when the range of its values is range(0,255) ??

Comment: Why do you think the variance can't be 521? The **standard deviation** can be anywhere between zero and half the range of the data (127.5 in this case) which means the variance can be anywhere between 0 and 127.5 ** 2.

Comment: I want to get a difference that is logical, how could it be useful to me to use a number as big as 521 to check the difference between values that can not get bigger than 255 ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the variance CAN be greater than the range of values. Here's an example:

```
data = [10, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0]
range of values = [0, 10]
mean = 5
var = ((10 - 5)^2 * 4 + (0 - 5)^2 * 4) / 8 = 200 / 8 = 25
```

The variance is above the maximum value the data can take. Perhaps what you want is the [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) which is the square root of the variance.

Comment: yeah it seems that I forgot to square root the results, I actually needed the standard deviation but used a formula for variance instead